# Creating Preload and Progressbar for angular.js app on startup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have many script in application and i want before app started and angular initialize user see a progress bar with percent. i try to implement this with twitter bootstrap progressbar and head.js but it dosent work:

```
$(function(){
  head.load([some scripts here],function(){
        $('#progressId').remove();
   })
});
```

but i dont khnow how to show percent. it's not important that i use headjs or anything the only important thing is the first initialize app and script loading user see a progress bar

Comment: http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/ check this one as well: https://github.com/DanWahlin/AngularOverlay

Comment: this is not that i wanting.i  wanting when browser download angular.js ,d3.js or other script files show a progress bar to user.

Comment: Are those files being loaded from a CDN or your own server? Check the second link I posted, it detects all XHR requests and shows a loading gif, you can get the percentage progress of that request as well, it's implemented in the first link I posted.

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand all my script is on the my server.you right but the problem is when i load an other app after angular initialize i can't inject that app in my main app.

Comment: Well then all you need is ALB, look at the first sentence on the first link I gave you: "An automatic loading bar using angular interceptors. It works automatically, so simply include it as a dependency and it will automatically display the progress of your $http requests" :) Pretty sure this is what you want.